# Why am I getting this Jave Error for the R string in the gui for the minecraft plugin

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am coding a Minecraft Plugin using of course Java for Minecraft 1.12
I have the latest version of Java and eclipse also the Bukkit Api.

This is the error I am getting:

```
String[] r *=* ("Spamming", "test1", "test2,", "test3", "Test34");
for (String reason : r)
```

The `=` is under red line with this error:

> ```
> Syntax error on token "=", Name expected after this tokenReasonGUI.java   /WarningSystem/src/listener line 28 Java Problem
> ```

full code:

```
package listeners;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.SkullType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;


import me.OctoberTroy.WarningSystem.MainClass1;

    public class ReasonGUI implements Listener{
    MainClass1 main = MainClass1.getPlugin(MainClass1.class);
    public Inventory rinv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9, "Select a reason to warn the player!");


    public ReasonGUI(Player player){
        if (player == null){
            return;
        }

    String[] r = ("Spamming", "test1", "test2,", "test3", "Test34");
    for (String reason : r);
```

Comment: Your array syntax is wrong. It should be `{ ... }` not `( ... )`

Comment: Voting to close as simple typographical error. This question is highly unlikely to help any other readers.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses braces to initialize an array.

```
String[] r = {"Spamming", "test1", "test2,", "test3", "Test34"};
```

Furthermore, although your program will compile, your for loop has no implementation. You cycle through each string in your newly declared array, but do nothing with it. Put the implementation for it as such:

```
for (String reason : r){
  // IMPLEMENTATION GOES HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you use curly braces {} for arrays, not parenthesis ().